# Connection Refused On Expect Script SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting, expect

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    set timeout 30
    #Edit for User
    set user user
    #Edit for Old Password
    set old oldpassword
    #Edit for New Password
    set new newpassword
    #get IP List from iplist.txt
    set f [open "/iplist.txt"]
    set data [read $f]
    set wpass [open "/wrongpassword.log" w]
    set nossh [open "/nossh.log" w]
    set success [open "/successful.log" w]
    close $f

    foreach line [split $data \n] {
        if {$line eq {}} continue
        spawn -noecho ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $user@$line
        expect {
            "assword:" {
                send "$old\r"
                expect {
                    "assword:" {
                            close
                            puts $wpass "$line"
                            continue
                            }}
                 expect {
                        "*" {
                            send "user set $user password=$new\r"
                            expect ">"
                            send "\r"
                            expect ">"
                            send "quit\r"
                            close
                            puts $success "$line"
                            continue
                            }}}}
        expect {
                "*" {
                close
                puts $nossh "$line"
                continue
                }}
        expect eof
    }

    close $wpass
    close $nossh
    close $success
```

This worked fine when I was testing it, but I was tarpiting ssh instead of blocking it so when I get a connection refused or a no route to host it errors out because the ssh connection is already closed by the client. I have tried removing close all together right before "puts $nossh "$line"" instead of close. I have also tried interact and expect eof, even though the continue command should go to expect eof anyway, but still errors out at this point. It works fine if the device has a different password or if no device on the list is unavailable or has ssh turned off. It also works fine if I tarpit the connection which leaves it open but not allowed to pass traffic. It seems like this is an issue with the SSH connection being closed before it reaches the next command. Just cant figure out how to get it to continue on with the next IP when it reaches one the ssh connection fails on. Also the log files work fine also when I tarpit but when it errors out because of no ssh it doesn't ever write to the log file for nossh so the issue is right there, just don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    foreach line [split $data \n] {
        if {$line eq {}} continue
        spawn -noecho ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $user@$line
        expect {
            "assword:" {
                send "$old\r"
                expect {
                    "assword:" {
                            close
                            puts $wpass "$line"
                            continue
                            }
                    ">" {
                        send "user set $user password=$new\r"
                        expect ">"
                        send "\r"
                        expect ">"
                        send "quit\r"
                        close
                        puts $success "$line"
                        continue
                        }
                    }
                }
            eof {
                puts $nossh "$line"
                continue
                }
            }
    }

    close $wpass
    close $nossh
    close $success
```

I was doing a couple things wrong one was splitting up the expect commands and I was using eof wrong. Also wildcards will not work right if the expect has more than one option, it will always choose the wildcard no matter the order you write it in. It works as expected now. Now just to do the same thing for my more complex script for other equipment.